# EmberJS and a bower CSS

Tags: css, ember.js, assets

I am using a Bower package with Bootstrap and a theme in an ember app. The theme is called admin lte, and it looks like the it's loading `adminlte.css` and then `bootstrap.css`.

The problem is that Bootstrap is supposed to be first, according to the examples of the theme. How do I affect the CSS loading order?

Comment: probably you load the theme yourself in the `ember-cli-build.js` file. Ember does not include anything automatically from bower.

Comment: I never found where the CSS where included. I ended up putting the theme manually in vendor.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to `app.import` them, and the ordering will be preserved.
See the see [Ember CLI guides section on style](https://ember-cli.com/user-guide/#styles) for information on this.

Comment: this works also if the template is in `bower_components`.